# Dynamically reference an array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to reference 1 index (there will be 30 different index) based on what the user's actions and then use ng-repeat to go through each item in the index.

Controller:

```
$scope.meals = [
    { title: 'Abs', url:"#/app/mworkouts",id: 100, img: "img/female.jpg", vid:"https://media.giphy.com/media/TLpGHso4sEJlS/giphy.gif",},
    { title: 'Arms', url:"#/app/browse",id: 2 , img: "img/male.jpg", vid:"https://media.giphy.com/media/ZYi2Lc03nrryw/giphy.gif"},
    { title: 'Biceps', url:"#/app/search",id: 3, img: "img/Spotify_2.jpg", vid:"https://media.giphy.com/media/zOleW7sjYngQ0/giphy.gif" },
    { title: 'Legs', url:"#/app/search",id: 4, img: "img/Spotify_4.jpg", vid:"https://media.giphy.com/media/srNYANrTyYeFW/giphy.gif" },
    { title: 'Core', url:"#/app/mworkouts",id: 5, img: "img/female.jpg", vid:"https://media.giphy.com/media/4YAkSYGsKieXK/giphy.gif" },
    { title: 'Back', url:"#/app/mworkouts",id: 6, img: "img/male.jpg", vid:"https://media.giphy.com/media/8eBAeU1W4kV68/giphy.gif" }
  ];
$scope.deserts = [
    { title: 'Chocolate', url:"#/app/mworkouts",id: 1 },
    { title: 'Cake', url:"#/app/browse",id: 2 },
    { title: 'Ice Cream', url:"#/app/search",id: 3 },
    { title: 'Sundae', url:"#/app/search",id: 4 },
    { title: 'Cherry Pie', url:"#/app/mworkouts",id: 5 },
    { title: 'Apple Pie', url:"#/app/mworkouts",id: 6 },
    { title: 'Pumpkin Pie', url:"#/app.mworkouts", id: 7}
  ];

$scope.allbooks = [{
    'book1': {
      title: "Eat Pray Don't Love",
      price: 3.99,
      workoutname: "meals"
    },
    'book2': {
      title: "Hello Fadder Hello Mudder",
      price: 19.99,
      workoutname:"deserts"
    }
  }, {
    'book2': {
      title: "DaVinci Code",
      price: 7.99,
      workoutname:"deserts"
    }
  }];
```

function that sets choice:

```
$scope.pick = function(selectedBook) {
    $rootScope.choice = selectedBook;
  }
```

and finally the HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="m in {{choice.workoutname}}">
        <div ng-if="meal_index==$index" ng-init="startCount=m.id">
          <img src="{{m.img}}" style="width:100%; height:100%;max-width:500px;">
          <img src="{{m.vid}}" style="width:100%; height:100%;max-width:500px;">
          <p>
          {{m.title}} {{m.id-40}}<!-- {{$index+1}} --> out of {{meals.length}} {{startCount}}
          <button ng-click='vs(m.id)'>Setter</button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Sorry about all the weird names...it's just an example. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Unless you have a real need to use $rootScope to store choice, stick with $scope.  Don't see the pick function wired also.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What doesn't work? What errors are reported? What happens?

Comment: There are no values in the view that relate to the set scope variables or methods. Weird names are fine and all, but it at least has to result in comprehensive code.

Comment: Sorry I am very very new to coding...I left out the pick code because I didnt think it was important to the problem (I will try to add it in). But can you tell me how I would dynamically access part of the array using ng-repeat. So should I put 'meals' in 'allbooks' because 'm in {{choice.workoutname}}' does not work... btw choice is set dynamically based on ng click ( example choice is allbooks[0].book1...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't uncommon to get this wrong as a newbie. But u need to understand angular/ionic in deep, mostly about array, objects and data binding. Hope this is helpful.

Below is one of the way u can do,

Controller:

```
var meals = [
    { title: 'Abs', url:"#/app/mworkouts",id: 100, img: "img/female.jpg", vid:"https://media.giphy.com/media/TLpGHso4sEJlS/giphy.gif"},
    { title: 'Arms', url:"#/app/browse",id: 2 , img: "img/male.jpg", vid:"https://media.giphy.com/media/ZYi2Lc03nrryw/giphy.gif"},
    { title: 'Biceps', url:"#/app/search",id: 3, img: "img/Spotify_2.jpg", vid:"https://media.giphy.com/media/zOleW7sjYngQ0/giphy.gif" },
    { title: 'Legs', url:"#/app/search",id: 4, img: "img/Spotify_4.jpg", vid:"https://media.giphy.com/media/srNYANrTyYeFW/giphy.gif" },
    { title: 'Core', url:"#/app/mworkouts",id: 5, img: "img/female.jpg", vid:"https://media.giphy.com/media/4YAkSYGsKieXK/giphy.gif" },
    { title: 'Back', url:"#/app/mworkouts",id: 6, img: "img/male.jpg", vid:"https://media.giphy.com/media/8eBAeU1W4kV68/giphy.gif" }
  ];

  var deserts = [
    { title: 'Chocolate', url:"#/app/mworkouts",id: 1 },
    { title: 'Cake', url:"#/app/browse",id: 2 },
    { title: 'Ice Cream', url:"#/app/search",id: 3 },
    { title: 'Sundae', url:"#/app/search",id: 4 },
    { title: 'Cherry Pie', url:"#/app/mworkouts",id: 5 },
    { title: 'Apple Pie', url:"#/app/mworkouts",id: 6 },
    { title: 'Pumpkin Pie', url:"#/app.mworkouts", id: 7}
  ];

  $scope.allbooks = [
    {
      category: "book1",
      title: "Eat Pray Don't Love",
      price: 3.99,
      workoutname: "meals"
    },
    {
      category: "book2",
      title: "Hello Fadder Hello Mudder",
      price: 19.99,
      workoutname: "deserts"
    },
    {
      category: "book3",
      title: "DaVinci Code",
      price: 7.99,
      workoutname: "deserts"
    }
  ];

  $scope.choices = '';
  $scope.pick = function(selectedBook) {
    if(selectedBook.workoutname === 'meals'){
      $scope.choices = meals;
      $scope.details.show();
    }else{
      $scope.choices = deserts;
      $scope.details.show()
    }
  };

  $scope.setter = function(id){
    //do something with id
  };

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('details.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-right'
  }).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.details = modal;
  });

  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.details.remove();
  });
```

HTML

```
<ion-view view-title="Search">
<ion-content>
   <div class="list card"
        ng-repeat="book in allbooks"
        ng-click="pick(book)">
      <p class="positive"><strong>{{book.title}}</strong></p>
      <p>Type: {{book.workoutname}}</p>
      <p>Price: {{'$'+book.price}}</p>
  </div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>

<script id="details.html" type="text/ng-template">
<ion-modal-view>
<ion-header-bar class="dark">
  <h1 class="title text-centerx">Details</h1>
  <button class="button button-clear ion-close" ng-click="details.hide()"></button>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
  <div class="list card"
       ng-repeat="choice in choices">
      <a class="item item-avatar" href="#">
        <img src="{{choice.img}}">
        <h2>{{choice.title}}</h2>
      </a>
      <img ng-if="choice.vid" src="{{choice.vid}}" style="width:100%; height:100%;max-width:500px;">
      <div>
        <button class="button button-balanced" ng-click='setter(choice.id)'>Setter</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
</script>
```